# Getting 'Nonetype is not callable' error but I don't know why

Tags: python, function, pip, keyboard-events, nonetype

I'm trying to create a reaction time game thing, however when I press enter after the hotkey is added I get a super long Nonetype error making reference to several different files.

```
import time
import datetime
import random
import keyboard

playing=True

def stop(playing):
    playing=False

input("Press enter when you're ready to test your reaction time!")
print("Press enter when you see the cat!")

time.sleep(1)

keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', stop(playing))

time.sleep(random.randint(3,6))

if(playing==True):
    keyboard.remove_hotkey('enter')
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    input("Press Enter!!!!")
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```

The idea of the hotkey is to stop the user from being able to just hold the enter button down. I don't know why this doesn't work.

I tried adding 'return playing' to the end of the function but that just gave me a similar error of 'bool is not callable'

Comment: You probably need to familiarise yourself with variable scope concepts in Python. Once you understand those you'll realise that your *stop()* function won't do what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop(playing)` returns `None`, so when you do:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', stop(playing))
```

it's exactly as if you did:

```
stop(playing)
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', None)
```

The second argument to `add_hotkey` is supposed to be a function (not the result of calling a function), so if you pass it `None`, it raises an error.

What I think you want to do is define your `stop` function so that it can be called with no arguments, and sets the global `playing` variable to False:

```
def stop()
    global playing
    playing = False
```

and then pass the function (without calling it yet) to `add_hotkey`:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', stop)
```

Comment: It is possible to pass `args` as shown in my answer but I believe OP may still want to at least use `nonlocal playing` if they insist on keeping the argument

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed this issue :)

Sorry if this was a simple issue, this is my first time using functions and i couldn't find a solution anywhere

Answer (score 0):

```py
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', stop(playing))
```

This prematurely **calls** the `stop` function and then passes `None` as the callback argument to `add_hotkey`. Then when the event is triggered `None` it is being attempted to be called.

Instead, you should use

```py
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', stop, args=(playing,))
```

as shown on the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api).